# How to set backgrond in alert dialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am new in android and developing one of application. In this application, I need to open `dialog box` about company info.

That box open success in every mobile but background of dialog display `white in some mobile` and `blank in some mobile.`

So, How can i `set background of particular color so display same in all mobiles.`

Below of my dialog alert code:

```
private void aboutas() {
        ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        tv.setText(Html
                .fromHtml("<font color='white'><br/> &nbsp &nbsp Version 1.0 <br/><br/> &nbsp &nbsp Developed by </font> <font color='#5C5CFF'> <a href='http://example.com/'>XYZ</a> </font><br/><br/>&nbsp &nbsp <font color='white'> Powered by </font> <font color='#5C5CFF'> <a href='http://example.com/'>XYZ</a> <br/><br/><br/></font> &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp <font color='white'> Copyright © 2015 <br/></font>"));

        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        String titlepage = "About wallperper app";
        alertDialog.setTitle(titlepage);
        alertDialog.setView(tv);
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Add your code for the button here.

            }
        });
        // Set the Icon for the Dialog
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_icon);
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

I tried to solve but not get it proper.

Any one have a idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set custom view programmatically like this way..

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, (ViewGroup) getCurrentFocus());
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(dialoglayout);
builder.show();
```

then after to get reference of component

e.g. `Button btn = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.button_id);`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a light theme and aren't particular about the specific color, then you can pass a theme id to the AlertDialog.Builder constructor.

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT)...
```

or

```
AlertDialog.Builder(this, AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT)...
```

or You can create a custom alertDialog and use a xml layout. in the layout, you can set the background color and textcolor.

Something like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ActivityName.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,(ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
dialog.setContentView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `layout xml` with your desired background color.

Place your `TextView,ImageView`.. components in the layout.

Inflate it to get the `View`

And finally set the `AlertDialog`'s view as the inflated `View`